# Libreoffice now get error when asked to open

Tags: lubuntu, software-center, libreoffice, 16.10

I began getting this error with 5.2. Uninstalled and reinstalled 5.3 with same result.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to reset your profile.

Close LibreOffice and run:

```
mv /home/jeff/.config/libreoffice/ /home/jeff/.config/libreoffice.bak
```

...and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the whole problem solved yet.  But the root of this is the Snap Package.   I have removed the Snap Package and rolling forward.